# Databinding Redirection to xml is not working in android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding

I have updated android studio to latest version(3.1.2) and now when I click on BindingClass with ctrl it's not opening xml file for it which was working in previous version. And I have tried the same thing with creating new project in same version of android studio but it's working on it.

So I am thinking that I have added some wrong dependencies or I have done something wrong. So please guide me regarding this issue.

Here is the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'false'
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'false'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        basic {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".basic"
//            versionName "0.1.9"
        }
        admin {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".admin"
//            versionName "0.1.9-admin"
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation(name: 'wikitudesdk', ext: 'aar')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'

    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.1.0'
    //    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'

    //    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'

    //    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the Project Level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
        maven {url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'}
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: It's occure some time i am also facing this issue.

Comment: @SameerJani thanks for response. So what is the solution for it ?

Comment: I have tried to find out many ways it's specially occur in Android Studio above 3.0.1.
Trying to find out solution whenever I get surely update you.:)

Comment: Oh , Thanks @SameerJani

Comment: Im here to tell you about the wonders of Android Studio 3.0 beta 6. After lots of testing with difference releases of AS, this one doesnt have the problems with generating xml/databinding references and also runs MUCH faster than the latest AS on my ubuntu system.

Comment: @brux Thanks for responding me.. You are absolutely correct. As I have mentioned you in Question its working with my new project. But It doesn't works with my existing old project.

Comment: Any solution for AS 3.1.2?

Comment: @Jatin no, still I am getting same issue. But now I am using android studio 3.0.1 for that specific project.

Comment: @RujulGandhi Humm! Thanks for the reply

Comment: Same issue in AS 3.1.3

Comment: yes but still not found solution.

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil if you will get any solution then please answer here.

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`

Comment: I have updated android studio to 3.2 and new classpath is for 3.2.0 but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

**For opening related XML**

Android Studio has a new icon for related XML redirection. My AS version is 3.2.1.

[image: sc3]

**An hack for opening Binding Class.**

- Ctrl + N (Open File)
- Type `ActivityMainBinding` {or first letters - `Amb for ActivityMainBinding` if you are smart enough :)
- Hit enter on `ActivityMainBinding`

[image: sc1]

[image: sc2]

FYI I faced this problem in Java class only, [Go to declaration] works well with kotlin.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to java class of binding, In previous version it directly open xml file. which is not working. I mean it should open xml file.

Answer (score 0):

add below code into the project level gradle file.

```
jcenter()
```

below gradle file in the project it working fine.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
  allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
```

}

```
 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Comment: I have already added this code to project level gradle. 
Let me add this code to show you.