# Android Studio 3.2 sync failed after update

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated from Android Studio 3.1.4 to 3.2. Now sync fails with the error message

> Sync finish event has not been received

How can this be fixed? Invalidate Caches/Restart did not help.

The ida log shows the following warning:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/wrapper/WrapperConfiguration
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getWrapperConfiguration(GradleUtil.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.getGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:208)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.doGetGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:194)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.getGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleManager.lambda$getExecutionSettingsProvider$2(GradleManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.getExecutionSettings(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:732)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager.doCreateFacade(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager.doGetFacade(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager.doInvoke(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager$MyHandler.invoke(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.getResolver(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:550)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperConfiguration PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle, 181.5540.7.32.5014246] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@5f6fe2bb
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600021/gradle-project-refresh-failed-already-finished

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can you please help me to resolve this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043566/databinding-redirection-to-xml-is-not-working-in-android-studio-3-1-2

Comment: did you test cleaning and rebuilding your projects?

Comment: Which grade classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:+ you kept? inside project level build.gradle.

Comment: Make sure you have `gradle-wrapper.jar` in `gradle/wrapper/` under the project dir.

Comment: @AnjalSaneen The jar is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I found was to remove Android Studio and reinstall Android Studio 3.2 from scratch.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it did not work for me. The solution proposed by @yohannes-ejigu-ademe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492823/android-studio-3-2-sync-failed-after-update#52542674 saying we have to delete "uses-sdk" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

*The problem might be different from OP but this is also a new issue in AS 3.2 which gives you Gradle sync error*

I had Gradle sync error for the last couple of days after I updated to AS 3.2 and in my case, the problem was one of my library modules contain the following in Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
```

and the solution was to **remove 'uses-sdk'** (in AndroidManifest.xml file) **in ALL the modules in your project**.

Comment: Did the trick for me, i had sync failed although no error was displayed and project was running fine, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Try to look into the log of the IDE, for my case it was a flutter plugin causing the issue..

You can navigate to the logs by clicking on show log in the gradle try again strip at the top.

or

go to

```
~/username/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio3.5/
```

and read the idea.log file.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/util/GradleConstants
 at io.flutter.utils.FlutterExternalSystemTaskNotificationListener.onSuccess(FlutterExternalSystemTaskNotificationListener.java:17)  
This line waste half of my day.

Comment: Same for me, I wasted my half of day due to this exception.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/gradle/wrapper/WrapperConfiguration

It seems like `WrapperConfiguration` class couldn't be found. Try these commands:

```
brew install gradle
gradle wrapper
```

The second line will install wrapper class. And then,

```
gradlew clean
```

Comment: The wrapper is installed. The build works from the command-line and worked from Android Studio 3.1.4.

Comment: Then I guess, removing and reinstalling it with those commands might help?

Comment: Your answer only applies to macOS